# Best way to configure root file system in an embedded linux environment

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, zynq

I am developing scripts for my embedded board ( a zynq board) and I need some scripts to be loaded prior to login. Since the filesystem is loaded into DDR memory, any modifications will be erased after a reboot. So for my development, I have to remove the SD card, then mount the filesystem on my development machine and after that, I have to unmount the FS and wrap u-boot headers on top of it. Finally write everything to SD card and see if everything is working or not. I was wondering if there is any better solution??? like reloading file system while linux is running???

Comment: There are many solutions, but no one knows your hardware.  One is just to include a standard rootfs attached to the Linux image.  This rootfs will use tftp or some other transfer method to send the file over network/serial to the target.  You can 'pivot' to this new ramfs.  If you only have an SD card, then how can anything else work?

Comment: I am using ZYBO for my project. http://store.digilentinc.com/zybo-zynq-7000-arm-fpga-soc-trainer-board/
What do you mean when you say: " If you only have an SD card, then how can anything else work?"

Comment: You have both USB and Ethernet.  Either one is good to transfer the rootfs to the target.  You just need to make a 'stub rootfs' with scripts to transfer a target rootfs from your host over either Ethernet or USB.  If you had **ONLY** an SD card and NO USB or Ethernet, then you might need a different solution.